# When pressed 'Enter', sum the input and clear it

Tags: javascript

I'm in the begin fase of learning JS. I'm trying to make a page were the user can put numbers in a text field. The user can press enter to add another number. When the user pressed enter the input field need to be cleared

The amounts entered must be added together and their total must be shown in a second text box.

my HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<p>Uw totaal:</p>
<input type="text" id="output">
```

My JS:

```
input = document.getElementById("input");
        input.onkeypress = function(event) {
            ceckKey(event);
        };

        function ceckKey(e) {
            // check for enter: e.key is for Firefox
            // if true, make input empty
            if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.key == 13) {
                input.value = "";
            }
            var number = +input.value;
            return number;
        }

        var total = 0
        total += checkKey();
        document.getElementById("output").value = total;
```

The keypress works in every browser. The problem is that i cannot sum the numbers. If i put it in the keypress function, the number will be cleared everytime you hit enter again.

I hope you guys can help!

Comment: Btw you probably wanted to name your function `checkKey()` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value **before** your clear it.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var total = 0;

input.onkeypress = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 ||  e.key == 13) {
    total += +input.value;
    output.value = total;
    input.value = "";
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="input">
<p>Uw totaal:</p>
<input type="number" id="output">
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot -

```js
 var total = 0;
input = document.getElementById("input");
output = document.getElementById("output");
input.onkeypress = function(e) {
  total = total + input.value * 1;
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
   input.value = "";
 }
  output.value = total;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<p>Uw totaal:</p>
<input type="text" id="output">
```

And hey, welcome to JS!

Answer (score 0):

you clear your input field too early.

```
 var number = 0
 function ceckKey(e) {
        // check for enter: e.key is for Firefox
        // if true, make input empty
        if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.key == 13) {
            number += input.value;
            input.value = "";
        }
        return number;
    }

    document.getElementById("output").value = number;
```

note that your `number` variable may not be declared inside of the checkKey function. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the output element outside of the ceckKey function.

This update IS not automatic. You must trigger it.
Also, check carefully that function. Callbacks can return a value but using the dame function for a callbacks and getting that output contents does not look good.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing the value of input before calculating the total. I have updated your code little bit to work as you intended.

```
input = document.getElementById("input");
output = document.getElementById("output");
input.onkeypress = function(event) {
    checkKey(event);
};
function checkKey(e) {
  // check for enter: e.key is for Firefox
  // if true, make input empty
  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.key == 13) {
    // Note : in the begining the output text box is empty, so while output is empty i have assign 0 as its value.
    outputValue = (output.value == '') ? 0 : output.value;
    total = parseInt(outputValue) + parseInt(input.value);
    input.value = "";

    // To update the total in output text box
    document.getElementById("output").value = total;

  }
}
```